# Keras input dimensions for a MLP

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have been training a multilayer perceptron using Keras to make a prediction on a function similar to that of a normal distribution. I have  input variables , and I have one output value .
When I set my input layer to have  neurons as such

```
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, activation= 'relu'))
```

the model learns with a  accuracy.
When I tried to use  neurons in my input layer as such

```
model.add(Dense(35, input_dim=4, activation= 'relu'))
```

my model learns it with an  accuracy.
I'm not understanding the logic behind this. Surely you have to have only  neurons for the input layer; what is happening with the other  neurons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly. In first example you have 4 input neurons and they are connected to 4 neurons. In second, 4 inputs are connected to 35 neurons. That's it, you simply add more neurons in hidden layer. Btw, what do you mean saying "learns it with an accuracy"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It learns with an accuracy.  So basically,  what you're saying, is that the "35" means that there are 35 neurons in the first hidden layer?

Comment: yes, in first case 4->4->(some other layers), in second: 4->35->(some other layers)